# Button background colour changing

Tags: plugins, react-native, react-native-ios, touchableopacity

I was trying to create an OTP screen with autofill functionality using the [react-native-otp-inputs](https://github.com/dsznajder/react-native-otp-inputs) plugin. Everything is working fine, but when I try to add any button below this OTPInputs component the background colour of the button gets changed to a greyish one.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import RNBootSplash from 'react-native-bootsplash';
import OtpInputs from 'react-native-otp-inputs';

export function AuthenticationScreen({navigation}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    RNBootSplash.hide({duration: 250});
  });

  const otpRef = useRef();

  const focusOTP = useCallback(() => {
    otpRef.current.focus();
  }, []);

  const resetOTP = useCallback(() => {
    otpRef.current.reset();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1}}>
      <OtpInputs
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
          width: '100%',
          paddingLeft: 30,
          paddingRight: 30,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: 'blue',
        }}
        inputContainerStyles={{
          borderWidth: 0,
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
          borderColor: 'black',
        }}
        inputStyles={{textAlign: 'center'}}
        handleChange={(code) => console.log(code)}
        numberOfInputs={6}
      />

      <View
        style={{
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          marginVertical: 40,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: 'red',
        }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            height: 50,
            width: 100,
            borderRadius: 20,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
          <Text>Continue</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

This happens only if the all the otp fields are filled. Please find the attached screenshot for a detailed view. [image: screenshot]

As you can see I haven't added any background colour to touchable opacity, still it is showing a grey colour after the otp inputs are filled. What may be the reason for this ?

Comment: it'd be better if you added code instead of image for code

Comment: Sure I'll update  it. @HassanKandil

Comment: @HassanKandil I've updated it , please check.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently when you end editing the OTP fields it changes the next touchable opacity.

As workaround you can add self enclosed touchable opacity with no width and height like this

```
<TouchableOpacity/>
```

And here is a full [example](https://snack.expo.io/@hassan190011/react-native-otp-inputs) with your code